# PHP isn't working with SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, ubuntu, lighttpd

Okay, so this is my first server I'm setting up.  I have a system running Ubuntu 11.10. I'm running Lighttpd and have PHP set up, but I want PHP and SQLite to work together. I installed them using:

```
sudo apt-get install lighttpd
sudo apt-get install php5-cgi
sudo apt-get install sqlite
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

PHP works fine, but any script with a sqlite command in it just returns a blank page. I turned on php error messages and ran this script:

```
<?php
echo sqlite_libversion();
echo "<br>";
echo phpversion();
?>
```

Which returns:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_libversion()
```

What's gone wrong? :(

`php -m` produces this:

> [PHP Modules] bcmath bz2 calendar Core ctype date dba  dom ereg exif
>   fileinfo filter ftp gettext hash iconv json libxml mbstring mhash
>   openssl pcntl pcre PDO pdo_sqlite Phar posix readline Reflection
>   session shmop SimpleXML soap sockets SPL sqlite3 standard sysvmsg
>   sysvsem sysvshm tokenizer wddx xml xmlreader xmlwriter zip zlib

Comment: What extension did you set in Php.ini file for sqlite?

Answer (score 2):

Extension in Php.ini file should be:

```
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
```

Comment: Where in the php.ini file should they go?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/all/php5-sqlite/filelist the php5-sqlite contains two extension modules

- pdo_sqlite.so -> http://docs.php.net/pdo
- sqlite**3**.so -> [http://docs.php.net/sqlite**3**](http://docs.php.net/sqlite3)

so it looks like `php5-sqlite` doesn't provide the module you're looking for.
If you don't have tons of legacy code I rather suggest you use [PDO](https://docs.php.bet/pdo), esp. since the sqlite module is going to be [moved from core php to pecl](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php) (nothing wrong with pecl though...):

> Since PHP 5.0 this extension was bundled with PHP. Beginning with PHP 5.4, this extension is available only via PECL.

Comment: How do I install this module?

Comment: I really don't know. I find it rather strange that `php5-sqlite` provides three .ini files, two of them match the two modules provided by the package. And then there's `/etc/php5/conf.d/sqlite.ini` but no `sqlite.so`. Strictly speaking this is not so much a developer question as one for administrators; you might get better answers on one of the other stackexchange servers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the sqlite extensions in your php.ini?

It seems this guy had the same issue: http://forum.alwaysdata.com/viewtopic.php?id=1034

The solution in that thread was to add

```
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
```

To php.ini, preferably under the "Dynamic Extensions" sections, but they could go anywhere.

Comment: Please summarize the linked text in this answer, otherwise it isn't of any use if / when the link breaks.