# I'm unable to run sqlite functions in php

Tags: php, apache, pdo, sqlite

When I run the following code

```
<?php
echo sqlite_libversion();
echo "<br>";
echo phpversion();
?>
```

I get this error

Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_libversion()

I was brought to this page [PHP isn't working with SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920995/php-isnt-working-with-sqlite/9921086#9921086?newreg=518956221293481ba5c99dc677f0a321)

Like the person who asked a similar question I typed php -m and the modules running are

bcmath bz2 calendar Core ctype date dba dom ereg exif fileinfo filter ftp gd gettext hash ice iconv json libxml mbstring mcrypt mhash mysql mysqli openssl pcntl pcre PDO pdo_mysql pdo_sqlite Phar posix Reflection session shmop SimpleXML soap sockets SPL sqlite3 standard sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm tokenizer wddx xml xmlreader xmlwriter zip zlib

From the advice given I put these in the dynamic extension section in php.ini

```
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
```

I restarted apache2 and unfortunately I am still getting the same error
And I confirmed I have 
lighttpd 
sqlite 
php5-sqlite installed and dependencies

I am running,
raspbian,
Apache/2.2.22 (Debian),
php5.4.4,
sqlite3,
SQLite Library  3.7.13,
SQLite3 module version  0.7,

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pdo + sqlite = use the PDO functions: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

Simply create a PDO object with the sqlite: protocol and off you go. Don't use the sqlite_... functions, they're something completely different.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction
looks like I have some reading to do ^_^